# Difference failed tasks vs killed tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

From Jobtracker web UI, I see this column called "Failed/Killed
Task Attempts".

I would like to know the distinction between them. I guess "Failed ones" mean tasks that really failed eventually after some retries (so no recovery was done at all?) while "Killed ones" mean tasks which are killed (due to timeout and so on) but they might be retried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few reasons Hadoop can kill tasks by his own decisions: 
a) Task does not report progress during timeout (default is 10 minutes) 
b) FairScheduler or CapacityScheduler needs the slot for some other pool (FairScheduler) or queue (CapacityScheduler). 
c) Speculative execution causes results of task not to be needed since it has completed on other place.

Answer (score 8):

Hadoop uses "speculative execution." The same task may be started on multiple boxes. The first one to finish wins, and the other copies are killed.

Failed tasks are tasks that error out.

Answer (score 1):

I would disagree with David little bit as timeout tasks are not marked as killed but instead marked as failed.

In my understanding below are definitions for failed vs killed tasks

Task can be Failed because of

1. task throws a runtime exception
2. sudden exit of the child JVM
3. timeout exceeding mapred.task.timeout

Task can be Killed because of

1. FairScheduler or CapacityScheduler needs the slot for some other pool (FairScheduler) or queue (CapacityScheduler).
2. Speculative execution causes results of task not to be needed since it has completed on other place.
3. Users may also kill or fail task attempts using the web UI or the command line

Answer (score 0):

A Failed task is attempt that threw an exception during Running,Killed task is a duplicate task killed in process of speculative execution.

Comment: and how can I see that exception? I see nothing in syslog or stderr under /mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/1 (on the master node)

Answer (score 0):

Failed tasks
1. A buggy map or reduce code (runtime exception error)
2. A sudden exit of jvm
3. A hanging task (it may trigger speculative execution if it is enabled)

Killed tasks
1. Speculative execution kills the long running job.
2. If a user himself kills a job.
3. Task tracker failure